# Compare multiple strings android

Tags: java, android, string-comparison

what I am trying to do is check if multiple srings are null in order to go to the next activity, something like this:

```
if( string1.equal(null) && ... stringN.equal(null))
{ Toast.makeText(this, "something is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
else
{ GO TO THE NEXT ACTIVITY}
```

all of the strings have to have content... Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have have a variable number of strings to check I would do something like the following:

```
private boolean validate(String... items) {
  for (String item : items) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(item)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Then your code would call the validate method with as many strings as you need to validate:

```
if (validate(string1, string2, stringN)) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "something is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else { 
  // GO TO THE NEXT ACTIVITY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are in a List or Array, then you could iterate them.

If using an ArrayList:

```
private boolean verify(final ArrayList<String> list)
{
    for (String entry : list)
    {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(entry))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or if using an array, same thing just changed the parameter to String[]:

```
private boolean verify(final String[] list)
{
    for (String entry : list)
    {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(entry))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
private String[] array;

private String one = "one";
private String two = "two";
private String three = "three";
private String four = "four";
private String five = "five";


private void someMethod(){
    if(isStringsNotNull(getStringArray())){
        //Start another activity
    } else {
        //Do something
    }
}

private String[] getStringArray(){
    return new String[]{one, two, three, four, five};
}

private Boolean isStringsNotNull(String[] array){
    for(String str: array){
        if(str == null){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Good answer @PerracoLabs, but isEmpty only check if the length is 0. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java8 / lambda, you can try using this function:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string2.split(" "))); // Split the string into list
        // compare the list with the source of the string, if match put into the list of result
        List<String> result = stringList.stream().filter(new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(String s) {
//                return string1.contains(s); // case sensitive
                return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(string1).find(); // case insensitive
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // check the match results
        if(result.size()<stringList.size()){
            Log.d("test", "onCreate: not match");
        }else{
            Log.d("test", "onCreate: match");
        }
```